# Best way to extract from an RDD Iterable in Scala

Tags: scala, rdd, iterable

If I have the following function and I want to split the Iterable to an RDD of `Var1` with an array of `Var2`, what is the best way to do it?

Here is my function:

```
def foo(rdds: RDD[(ID, Iterable[(Var1,Var2)])]) : RDD[(Var1,Array[Var2])] = {
   rdds.map(x => (x._2.map(it => it._1).asInstanceOf[Var1], (x._2.map(it => it._2).toArray)))
}
```

And here is my sample input data:

```
//RDD[(ID, Iterable[(Var1,Var2)...])]
RDD[("ID1",Iterable[(1,4),(1,8),(1,15)])],
RDD[("ID2",Iterable[(2,18),(2,29)])]
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
//RDD[(Var1,Array[Var2])]
RDD[1,(4,8,15)],
RDD[2,(18,29)]
```

And while my above code works. It seems that it is unnecessary to traverse `x._2` twice to get both parts of the Iterable and I don't like how I have to an explicitly perform an `asInstanceOf[Var1]` conversion to change the Iterable type.

Is there a better way to extract the elements from the Iterable and place them in the new RDD grouped by `Var1`?

Comment: Care to comment/accept on my answer? @EliSquared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the way you are obtaining `var1`. According to the data you have shown, the `var1` values in the `Iterable` is same. So no need to iterate through the `Iterable` twice. You can do something like :

```
def foo(rdds: RDD[(ID, Iterable[(Var1,Var2)])]) : RDD[(Var1,Array[Var2])] = {
   rdds.map(x => (x._2.head._1, (x._2.map(it => it._2).toArray)))
}
```

Which will give the required result.

*NOTE* - This works only when `x._2` has atleast one element present. If there is a possibility that `x._2` is empty, then `x._2.headOption.getOrElse((defaultVar1, defaultVar2))._1` might be a good idea.